# math operations (add, divide) of two series in influxdb 0.9?

Tags: mysql, time-series, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB 0.9, graphing with Grafana, mysql plugin installed and working.

I need few key metrics for our system:

```
innodb_buffer_read_hit_ratio = ( 1 - innodb_buffer_pool_reads/innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests) * 100
innodb_buffer_usage = ( 1 - innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total) * 100
```

After reading through docs I find that [`inner join` in InfluxDB 0.9 no longer possible](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/concepts/08_vs_09.html). What are my options? change to another time-series db? Install 0.8?

Comment: upon further poking I found influxdb does not even support `max(value) - mind(value)` expressions. So field value can only be used once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions and mathematical operators can only be applied to field values in the same measurement. If `innodb_buffer_pool_reads` and `innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` are fields in the same measurement, that query will work (although only on a recent nightly build or the eventual 0.10.0 release, due to https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/4046).

Comment: a side question: how soon can we get cross series math operations?

Comment: That issue (https://github.com/influxdb/influxdb/issues/4046) is fixed in the 0.10 nightlies available now, and in the official 0.10 release in late January.